The structure of elementary finite Moufang loops
Before asking the question, I recall some standard definitions of non-associative algebra.
A magma is a set $X$ endowed with a binary operation $X\times X\to X$, $(x,y)\mapsto xy$.
A subset $S\subseteq X$ is a submagma if $\forall x,y\in S\;(xy\in S)$.
A magma $X$ is called
$\bullet$ a semigroup if its binary operation is associative;
$\bullet$ a quasigroup if for every $a,b\in X$ there exist unique $x,y\in X$ such that $ax=b$ and $ya=b$;
$\bullet$ a loop if $X$ is a quasigroup possessing an element $e\in X$ such that $xe=x=ex$ for all $x\in X$;
$\bullet$ a group if $X$ is an associative loop;
$\bullet$ Moufang if $(xy)(zx)=x((yz)x)=(x(yz))x$ for every $x,y,z\in X$.
By the classical theorem of Moufang, every Moufang loop $M$ is diassociative, which means that any two elements of $M$ generated an associative subloop in $M$.
So, Moufang loops are "almost" groups (for more information in this direction, see this survey of Gagola III).
Now I define the main notion I am interested in.
Definition. A magma $X$ is called elementary if every element $x\in X$ is contained in a submagma $S\subseteq X$ whose cardinality $|S|$ is a prime number.
It is well-known that every elementary Abelian group is the direct sum of cyclic groups of a order $p$.
The structure of elementary finite groups has been revealed by Luneburg and also by
Cheng Kai Nah, M. Deaconescu, Lang Mong Lung, Shi Wujie who proved the following
Theorem: If $X$ is an elementary finite group, then it satisfies one of three conditions:

$|X|=p^r$ for some prime number $p$ and some $r$;

$X$ is a Frobenius group of cardinality $|X|=p^rq$ for some distinct prime numbers $p,q$ and some $r$;

$X$ is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_5$.


I am interested in possible generalizations of this classification theorem to finite Moufang loops.

Problem. Let $X$ be an elementary finite Moufang loop. Is $|X|\in\{p^r,p^rq,60\}$ for some prime numbers $p,q$ and some $r$?

Remark. In the last decades many classical theorems in Theory of Groups (for example, the tehorem of Lagrange, Sylow, Hall) have been generalized to finite Moufang loops, see this survey of Gagola III. So, maybe a classification of elementary groups also can be extended to Moufang loops?
